# How to tell a fragment that an Activity was finished?

Tags: android, kotlin

When an action is performed I am finishing the activity that I am currently on and landing on the fragment that was previously opened.
My question is, is there a way to tell that fragment that is being resumed from finishing a specific activity?

Comment: Why do you need this? Seems like a codesmell. The "previous" fragment in the stack will be resumed, if you started an activity expecting a result and the result is not part of a common (shared) viewModel, or stored in a "repository" of some kind (where both the finishing activity **and** the resuming fragment have access to), then your other option is to [start activity for result](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) and pick the result you want from there.

Comment: You're not landing on the fragment that was previously opened, you're landing on the (previously opened) activity that's hosting the fragment that was previously opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LiveData` approach.

Create a constant in `companion object` in fragment class as follow:

```
companion object {
    val _isActivityFinished = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isActivityFinished: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _isActivityFinished
}
```

In `onDestroy()` of your activity

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    _isActivityFinished.postValue(true)
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

In fragment, observe the state of this variable

```
isActivityFinished.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    if (it) {
        // do your work.. it has been returned from activity
    }
}
```